# Increment Number but skip the first time Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to set a loop that increments a variable but doesn't do it the first time around. This is the code, I know I'm close so I'm hoping for some guidance.

```
offset = 0
while do 
  if offset = 0 
    nil
  else
    offset += 1 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your attempt. First of all, your statement `if offset = 0` isn't checking if `offset` equals zero, it's *setting* it to zero. To check for equality, use `==`:

Secondly, even if you fix the first issue, the `else` of your condition will *never* fire, because `offset` will always be zero and therefore never incremented.

Third, if you have nothing to do in an `if` block, you don't need to put `nil`, just skip directly to the `else`:

```
  if offset == 0 
  else
    offset += 1 
  end
```

Even better, just negate the expression and skip the `else` entirely:

```
  if offset != 0 
    offset += 1 
  end
```

Also, `while do` isn't a valid Ruby construct. You can either write something like `while true do` or use `loop do`.

More generally speaking, if you need to execute some code before the offset is incremented, just put that code *before* the offset is incremented:

```
offset = 0
loop do 
  # your code goes here

  offset += 1 
end
```

And here's a more "Ruby-ish" way to do it:

```
0.step do |offset|
  # your code goes here
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
offset = 0
first_loop = true
loop do 
  offset += 1 unless first_loop

  code here

  first_loop = false
end
```